# Insert task to Queue only if unique

Tags: 7, cron, queue

I wanted a way to only insert items into the Queue when it was not already added. I want to have a large queue and work my way through it, simply adding as required. Previously I was deleting the queue and recreating on a set time table.

I couldn't find any way of doing this, or any discussion other than 'it's not possible.

I created the method below. I have not used it for huge queues yet, but I post it here in the hope that better options if available might get posted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to extend the systemqueue. I called mine Unique. This will serialise the data use db_merge to insert only if it doesn't exist.

```
class Unique extends SystemQueue {

  public function createItem($data) {

    // save doing this twice
    $serial_data = serialize($data);

    // ignoring expire
    $query = db_merge('queue')
    ->key(array('name' => $this->name, 'data' => $serial_data))
    ->fields(array(
        'name' => $this->name,
        'data' => $serial_data,
        'created' => time(),
    ));
    return (bool) $query->execute();
  }
}
```

You then add the variables to hook_install() or hook_enable().

```
variable_set('queue_class_[your queue name]', 'Unique');
```

matching [your queue name] to the queue name, e.g if you used this:

```
DrupalQueue::get('update_profile_tasks')->createQueue();
```

the variable would be:

```
variable_set('queue_class_update_profile_tasks', 'Unique');
```

Thanks to [this](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/drupal-7-queues-api) for getting me on track. Updated answer to be cleaner thanks to comment suggestions.

Comment: You could simply use `db_update()` instead of checking if there is a row for that data. `db_update()` updates the existing row, or creates it when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, you don't use `variable_set()` in this case, but `$conf` in settings.php since it is something that should be changed before Drupal completes its bootstrap phase.

Comment: @kiam Think you mean `db_merge()`?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to get the key if I use db_merge, and doesn't that basically check if it exists, and then updates/inserts? I am not sure that makes it better? Regarding the variable, I'd assumed this would be done on module install. I'll make that clearer.

Comment: @Clive Ops... Yes, that.

Comment: No, you just tell that you don't want to duplicate a row with that content in the _data_ database field. `db_merge('queue')->key('data')`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Awesome, just changed it and works great. I'll update the answer. Thank you!